# Packet Sniffing with pcap Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, packet, pcap, sniffing

I am trying to write a packet sniffing program in C and I am experiencing a segmentation fault when I try running the program after successful compilation.  I have tried to identify the exact line of code that causes the program to segfault by commenting out some of the code and recompiling the program and then rerunning the smaller version of my program.  Here is my code.

```
void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
   printf("Got a packet\n");
}

int main()
{
  pcap_t *handle;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  struct bpf_program fp;
  char filter_exp[] = "ip proto icmp";
  bpf_u_int32 net;

  // Step 1: Open live pcap session on NIC with name eth3
  handle = pcap_open_live("eth3", BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf); 

  // Step 2: Compile filter_exp into BPF psuedo-code
  pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net);      
  pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp);                             

  // Step 3: Capture packets
  pcap_loop(handle, -1, got_packet, NULL);                

  pcap_close(handle);   //Close the handle 
  return 0;
}
```

After commenting out the code and recompiling the program and rerunning the program, I have found that the segfault occurs at the `pcap_compile` line:

```
pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net);
```

When I compile and run a program with everything after the `handle` (Step 1) line commented out, the program runs without segfaulting and nothing happens.  As soon as I include the `pcap_compile` statement by making it active in the program, the program segfaults.  Does anyone know what could be the problem, whether it's with the `pcap_compile` call or something else?

Comment: In any reasonable environment you should be able to use a debugger to learn the exact failure point from a core dump produced by the seg fault. E.g. in gdb, you'd use the `where` or `backtrace` command.

Comment: Before even asking you should fix your program to check the return values of all your function calls and stop if these functions show an error instead of proceeding as you do currently. That's basic programming hygiene to catch problems early instead of trying to debug it later. It could for example be that `pcap_open_live` already fails and you then call `pcap_compile` with an invalid `handle`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `pcap_compile()` and understood how to use it?

Comment: You don't initialize variable `net` before using it in your function call. You should enable proper warnings in your compiler. It should warn you about such issues.

Answer (score 2):

Steffen Ullrich is 100% correct here.

If you're going to call any routine that returns a `pcap_t *`, such as `pcap_open_live()`, you must check to make sure it succeeds, by checking whether it returns a null pointer or not:

```
handle = pcap_open_live("eth3", BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf); 
if (handle != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open eth3: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
```

If it fails and returns a null pointer, then `pcap_compile()` - and other libpcap routines - will crash if you pass that null pointer to it as the first argument.

If you comment out the call to `pcap_open_live()`, then `handle` isn't set to anything, so it contains an unknown value.  *If* that value *happens* to point to a location in memory such that *if* `pcap_compile()`, `pcap_setfilter()`, and `pcap_loop()` don't happen to crash, *then* it will *appear as if* the program is working - but it's not.

So you should check whether `pcap_open_live()` succeeds, as in the example above - *and* you should check whether `pcap_compile()`, `pcap_setfilter()`, and `pcap_loop()` succeed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I want to remind that the first param of function `pcap_open_live` you called is your Linux's network interface. So you must make sure that your Linux has the network interface named **eth3**. You can check your Linux's network interface by the `ifconfig -a` command, and if you find that there exists **no** interface named **eth3**, then this may be where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a segmentation fault when I tried to run Wenliang Du's [SEED lab code](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_16.04/PDF/Sniffing_Spoofing.pdf) on sniffing and spoofing . But it ran fine when run with `sudo`. It is mentioned in comments [here](https://cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Etjp/cs55/code/sniffspoof/sniff.c) that it won't run without `sudo` since it won't have right to interface. Maybe you have the same issue.